# How do we verify if Sequel.connect opened our SQLite3 database in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, sequel

We are trying to find out if our Rails 3.1.12 app opens the SQLite3 database (version 3.6 or above) with gem sequel. Here is what we did:

1. `rails console`
2. In the Rails console session, typed the following command:

   ```
   sequel = Sequel.connect('sqlite://development')
   ```

   It returns:

   ```
   => #<Sequel::SQLite::Database: "sqlite://development">
   ```

   Also sequel.class returns:

   ```
   => Sequel::SQLite::Database
   ```

However when trying to select from the database with `sequel.execute` or check a table with `sequel.schema`, the returned text says that the table does not exist.

We are not quite sure if the database (development here) has been opened or not. How do we check that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Offhand I'd say you can try:

```
DB.test_connection
=> true
```

The documentation for [`test_connection`](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Database.html#method-i-test_connection) says:

> Attempts to acquire a database connection. Returns true if successful. Will probably raise an Error if unsuccessful. If a server argument is given, attempts to acquire a database connection to the given server/shard.

Years ago we'd use a benign query to tell if the connection is alive. You can try:

```
DB["select datetime('now');"].first
```

Which returns:

```
{
    :"datetime('now')" => "2013-06-25 06:23:44"
}
```

You'll probably want to catch any exceptions that might be raised if the query fails, but that would indicate that the connection was down too.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can also pass a `:test => true` option to the `connect()` method which achieves the same thing as `test_connection()`

Answer (score 3):

**Since version 5.0.0, Sequel verifies the connection by default** (the default value of the `test` option is now `true`).

As [Michael Berkowski noted in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287623/how-do-we-verify-if-sequel-connect-opened-our-sqlite3-database-in-rails#comment42339987_17290682), the `Sequel.connect` method accepts a boolean `test` option. The option used to default to false before Sequel 5.0.0. [The current docs](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html#label-General+connection+options) say:

> Whether to test that a valid database connection can be made (true by default)

When set, this option causes Sequel to call `#test_connection` on the new db object.