# Ruby: Catching Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, sequel

I'm using Docker to run my Ruby app, with MySQL as a database. I need for my Ruby app to wait until MySQL has finished loading and a connection can be made.

I'm using the following code:

```
def connect_to_db
  begin
    puts "Trying to connect to Mysql"
    Sequel::Model.db = Sequel.connect( // Connection stuff in here )
  rescue Sequel::Error => e
    puts "Mysql connection failed #{e.message}: Retrying."
    retry
  end
end

connect_to_db()
```

This runs once, then I get an error - `Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: Mysql2::Error: Unknown MySQL server host (25)` - It doesn't go into the `rescue` block and doesn't retry.

I've tried `rescue Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError` but this gives the same result.

What do I need to rescue here?

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that Sequel doesn't connect until it needs to run a query, and you aren't attempting to run a query inside the connect_to_db method.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with [db.test_connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287623/how-do-we-verify-if-sequel-connect-opened-our-sqlite3-database-in-rails):

```
def connect_to_db_with_mysql_driver
  begin
    puts "Trying to connect to Mysql"
    db = Sequel.connect(
            // Connection stuff
          )
    if db.test_connection == true
      Sequel::Model.db = db
    else
      raise "Mysql connection failed."
    end
  rescue => ex
    puts ex
    puts "Retrying..."
    retry
  end
end
```